# Testing/mocking JAX-WS

Tags: java, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS client generated from WSDL with wsimport. I would like to write some tests for it - how it behaves on timeout, exception, all possible responses from the server...

How can I use a custom, mock back-end for such a client? I know I can put up a real HTTP server, but that seems like an overkill.

Comment: What about [soapui service mocking](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/concept.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used an intercepting handler, which was able to throw exceptions or return a custom result. Sadly, I don't have the code at hand. I also think it's dependent on the application server you are using.

As starting point you might have a look at [mkyongs tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/), which uses SOAPHandlers.

Comment: As far as I understand, the handlers are higher level. Some kind of pre- and post-processing, executed around the backend. Actually I want to test my custom handlers as well and how they react to various failure modes from backend.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP servers like jetty are lightweight and can be used for unit testing without adding much to the test-case execution time.

Just use properties to point your unit-test soap client (wired with the handler) to the right (localhost) URL, and mount up a corresponding endpoint at the same address. If you are using CXF, I've put up an example JUnit rule [here](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf).